# Howto split declaration and implementation when using std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11

When I have a struct with a member function which I specialize with `std::enable_if` how can I then split the declaration from the implementation?

Example code (in [ideone](http://ideone.com/tqpdg7))

```
struct node
{
  template < class T >
  void analyze(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = 0)
  {
    std::cout << "is_arithmetic type " << t << "\n";
  }

  template < class T >
  void analyze(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = 0)
  {
    std::cout << "is_floating_point type " << t << "\n";
  }

  void analyze(bool t)
  {
    std::cout << "is bool type " << t << "\n";
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like any templated method:

```
struct node {
  template <class T>
  void analyze(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = 0);

};

template <class T>
void node::analyze(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type*) {
    std::cout << "is_arithmetic type " << t << "\n";
}
```

Note that you don't have template specialization here (you cannot do partial specialization for member function), you have different overloads.

Comment: That was to obvious. I tried several other versions. Thanks a lot! You're right, I'm overloading here.

Answer (score 1):

I would write different helper functions and tag dispatch.

```
template < class T >
void analyze(T t, int_tag);

template < class T >
void analyze(T t, float_tag );

void analyze(bool t, bool_tag );

template<class T>
auto get_tag();

void analyze( T t ){ return analyze(t, get_tag<T>());
```

Now we split the overload routing (`get_tag`) from the overloads via tag dispatching.

How you define your tags (`std::integral_constant` or `struct int_tag` or `tag<int>` or whatever) is up  to you; they just have to be mutually incompatible and empty.

How `get_tag` is written is also up to you; `if constexpr` in C++17, using or `static_if` or SFINAE or traits class constructs in C++11/14.

I would hold the definition of `get_tag` is part of the interface of `analyze` not implementation; instead of using enable if directly we separate the overload resolution rules, expose that, then put the implementation of the business logic elsewhere.

Comment: While this a good generic solution I'll choose the one with `enable_if` because I can break my problem down to a `if ... else` kind. But I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think that an anonymous default template parameter is a better solution since you don't have to copy the enable_if condition twice.

```
struct node
{
    template <class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
    void analyze( T t );
};

template <class T, typename>
void node::analyze( T t )
{
    std::cout << "is_arithmetic type " << t << "\n";
}
```

I know that it doesn't fit for the specific example, for it does answer the question.